# Listing authors who cite me

Tags: citations

While looking for good independent recommenders I found myself in need of a tool that can automatically compose a list of names that have cited my papers. Yes there are many ways to find out which "papers" cite a given paper, but if you have multiple papers and citations, extracting author names from citation list becomes challenging and time consuming very quickly. Is there a tool to do that? If not this sounds very useful and it may make sense to build such a tool, if you find it useful too.

(I guess you don't often need to find independent recommenders from strangers, but there are a couple of use cases at least, such as green card applications, job applications, etc.)

Comment: ResearchGate seems to have this feature for author profiles. Not sure how accurate it is. There also doesn't seem to be any way to export the data.

Comment: What field of research are you in? Many solutions will be field dependent

Comment: @mmeent computer science

Answer (score 1):

### Microsoft Academic

*Microsoft Academic* does show such information: Click on a researcher profile, go to the tab `Cited By`, then look at the column (to the left of the screen) titled `Top Authors`. Here is [an example for Christian Drosten](https://academic.microsoft.com/author/204599282/citedby/search?q=Christian%20Drosten&qe=Join(RId%252CComposite(AA.AuId%253D204599282))&f=&orderBy=0&pi=1):

[image: List of authors who cite Christian Drosten frequently]

If you have a profile at Microsoft Academic and claimed your publications, you can see a similar list regarding your own 'citers'.

---

### CrossRef

An alternative approach would be the following: You could gather all the DOIs from the papers that cite you, loop through it to access [CrossRef's API](https://github.com/CrossRef/rest-api-doc) via `https://api.crossref.org/works/{DOI}`, and extract the respective `author`-field.